# XML на андроиде

Tags: android, c++, xml

Какая есть простая, легковесная и мультиплатформенная с++ библиотека для работы с XML на андроиде?
Мне посоветовали pugixml и rapidxml, но я не нашёл информации об их мультиплатформенности.

Comment: Что значит "мультиплатформенная на андроиде"?

Comment: чтобы её можно было использовать на Linux, Windows и, самое главное, на андроиде.

Comment: По идее, любая (почти) java библиотека будет без проблем работать на всех платформах.

Comment: Мне нужно на с++, забыл добавить это в вопрос, хотя в тэге это есть.

Comment: Возможно, вы тут найдёте ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387610/what-xml-parser-should-i-use-in-c

Comment: но ведь там нет ни слова про андроид или мультиплатформенность

Comment: @Виталий можно узнать, почему именно C++, а не Java?

Comment: потому что я программирую на с++, а не на джаве

Comment: @Виталий, я в этом, конечно, не разбираюсь, но, вроде, подключить в java можно любую либу на крестах и в самой либе ничего не надо для нужной вам кросплатформенности делать.